# Broken DAG: (...) No module named docker

Tags: docker, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I have BigQuery connectors all running, but I have some existing scripts in Docker containers I wish to schedule on Cloud Composer instead of App Engine Flexible.

I have the below script that seems to follow the examples I can find:

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately
    'start_date': yesterday,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least 5 minutes
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

schedule_interval = '45 09 * * *'

dag = DAG('xxx-merge', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval)

hfan = DockerOperator(
   task_id = 'hfan',
   image   = 'gcr.io/yyyyy/xxxx'
 )
```

...but when trying to run it tells me in the web UI:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/xxxx.py] No module named docker
```

Is it perhaps that the Docker is not configured to work inside the Kubernetes cluster that Cloud Composer runs?  Or am I just missing something in the syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running docker operator from Google Cloud Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185485/running-docker-operator-from-google-cloud-composer)

Comment: It’s a couple of years since I asked this question :) these days I use KubernetesPodOperator instead. Installing docker or any other extra configuration on Airflow didn’t work out well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in other answers, the Docker Python client is not preinstalled in Cloud Composer environments. To install it, add it as a PyPI dependency in your environment's configuration.

**Caveat**: by default, `DockerOperator` will try to talk to the Docker API at `/var/run/docker.sock` to manage containers. This socket is *not* mounted inside Composer Airflow worker pods, and manually configuring it to do so is *not recommended*. [Use of `DockerOperator` is only recommended in Composer if configured to talk to Docker daemons running outside of your environments](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/faq#expandable-14).

To avoid more brittle configuration or surprises from bypassing Kubernetes (since it is responsible for managing containers across the entire cluster), you should use the `KubernetesPodOperator`. If you are launching containers into a GKE cluster (or the Composer environment's cluster), then you can use `GKEPodOperator`, which has more specific GCP-related parameters.

Comment: Agreed, this is what I eventually ended up with

Answer (score 8):

I got it resolved by installing docker-py==1.10.6 in the PyPI section of composer.

However, to get DockerOperator to work properly requires a bit more effort as the composer workers do not have access to the Docker daemon. Head to the GCP console and perform the following steps; after getting [cluster credentials](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart#get_authentication_credentials_for_the_cluster)).

1. Export current deployment config to file

   `kubectl get deployment airflow-worker -o yaml --export > airflow-worker-config.yaml`
2. Edit airflow-worker-config.yaml ([example link](https://github.com/marc-chan/cloud_composer_examples/commit/f3e6a202ef0bfd2214385def7e36be33db191df6#diff-fc2e428a07c8d60059e54e5154f0c540)) to mount docker.sock and docker, grant privileged access to airflow-worker to run docker commands
3. Apply deployment settings

   `kubectl apply -f airflow-worker-config.yaml`

Comment: To new readers, this is not a recommended reconfiguration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63428706/1380918. There is also no guarantee that patches to `airflow-worker` will persist if you update or upgrade your environment. Consider `GKEPodOperator` as the recommended solution for launching containers.

Answer (score 5):

This means: whereever your Airflow instance is installed, the Python package named `docker` is missing.

If I configure my personal machine, I can install missing packages with

```
pip install docker
```

**EDIT**

Within the source code of the docker component https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/docker_operator.html

there is an import statement:

```
from docker import Client, tls
```

So the new error `cannot import name Client` seems to me to be connected to a broken install or a wrong version of the `docker` package.

Comment: Ahh ok, so I should install that in the PyPi section!  Will try it now, thanks!

Comment: Hmm well close but now after installing docker I get `Broken DAG: [...] cannot import name Client` - is this the same thing or a different issue?

Comment: Great thank you - I will try it with a new docker version and environment

Comment: Is it possible it should be installing `pip install docker-py` ?  (no, its from 2016 https://pypi.org/project/docker-py/ )

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386003/airflow-inside-docker-running-a-docker-container

Comment: I have when I was installing airflow on my own server, but this is via Google Cloud Composer so I don't have server access - I do suspect that they may have to configure that though

Comment: `Client` was renamed to `DockerClient` in docker>=2.0.0 so I'm trying to install `docker==1.10.6`

Comment: This is still not working - the docker install fails when I try via its pip section, I'm waiting for some answer from Google on if it is supported

Comment: All python packages need to be installed into the virtual env which airflow is using (even docker) and not system wide/globablly for airflow to be able to access them

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem in my case was adding the word "docker" inside the Dockerfile

```
&& pip install pyasn1 \
&& pip install apache-airflow[crypto,docker,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
&& pip install 'redis==3.2' \
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in tobi6's answer, you need to have the PyPI package for docker installed in your Composer environment. There are instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies) for installing PyPI packages in your environment at a particular package version.