# Google Cloud Composer - Deploying Docker Image

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Definitely missing something, and could use some quick assistance!

Simply, how do you deploy a Docker image to an Airflow DAG for running jobs? Does anyone have a simple example of deploying a Google container and running it via Airflow/Composer?

Comment: However, see the trouble I am having here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253082/broken-dag-no-module-named-docker - it seems Docker python module is not installed

Comment: There's an alternative solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185485/running-docker-operator-from-google-cloud-composer - but again, it's not optimal

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Docker Operator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py), included in the core Airflow repository.

If pulling an image from a private registry, you'll need to set a connection config with the relevant credentials and pass it to the `docker_conn_id` param.

Comment: Thanks so much! Any advice on getting beyond this issue? Unfortunately, I had to setup a custom plugin to the newest github push( See: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/49556917d9a3e9192d9043afd6cf3ca7939a2403)

Basically, took the most up-to-date docker operator and created it as a custom plugin. This is google composer specific, in some way, but I am getting the following error:
`bind address needs a port: {0}".format(addr)`

Do you think i need to do the aforementioned, setup `docker_conn_id`? How do I set this up with composer?? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Even if i roll back packaging i still get an error with binding the port, i must be missing something again, because it is not clear to me how to generate this information for Composer, looking at the hook code:
`      extra_options = conn.extra_dejson
        self.__base_url = base_url
        self.__version = version
        self.__tls = tls
        self.__registry = conn.host
        self.__username = conn.login
        self.__password = conn.password
        self.__email = extra_options.get('email')
        self.__reauth = False if extra_options.get('reauth') == 'no' else True`

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience using Google Composer. If this doesn't get resolved and is a blocker for you, I might suggest spinning up your own Airflow or using a managed service. 

https://github.com/jghoman/awesome-apache-airflow#airflow-deployment-solutions

Comment: Yeah, i think you are right. Ugh, put so much effort into this and so close.