# write a file from a docker container in google-cloud-composer

Tags: python, docker, airflow, google-cloud-composer, dockerpy

Some context: 
I'm using `composer-1.3.0-airflow-1.10.0`

Installed PyPi package `docker===2.7.0`

For a while I tried to use the DockerOperator, but I need to pull images from a private gcr.io registry located in another gcp-project, and that is a mess.

I won't go into the details of why I gave up on this.. I switched to a simple `PythonOperator` used to pull and run the docker image. Here how the Operator goes:

```python
def runImage(**kwargs):
    workingDir = "/app"
    imageName = "eu.gcr.io/private-registry/image"
    volume = {"/home/airflow/gcs/data/": {"bind": "/out/", "mode": "rw"}}
    userUid = os.getuid()
    command = getContainerCommand()
    client = getClient()
    print("pulling image")
    image = pullDockerImage(client, imageName)
    print("image pulled. %s", image.id)
    output = client.containers.run(
        image=imageName,
        command=command,
        volumes=volume,
        privileged=True,
        working_dir=workingDir,
        remove=True,
        read_only=False,
        user=userUid)
    print output
    return True


task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="test_pull_docker_image",
    python_callable=runImage,
    dag=dag
)
```

Image is well pulled. And it run (which was already a victory).

The container write some files to `/out/`, which I mounted as a volume to `/home/airflow/gcs/data` with `rw` rights.

The `working_dir, user, privileged, read_only` options were added for test, but I don't think they're relevent.

The files are not created.
writing a file directly in pyhton to `/home/airflow/gcs/data` works just fine.

The container itself is a complied C#.
Locally if the container fails to write the files I get an error (like `Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/out/file.txt' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied`)

But when I run the DAG inside airlfow composer everything looks just fine, container output is as expected, no error raised.

Maybe the Dockerfile could be usefull:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "programm.dll"]
```

So the question is,

Why does it not write the files? And how to allow the container to write files to `/home/airflow/gcs/data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue thanks to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328627/unable-to-write-file-from-docker-run-inside-a-kubernetes-pod)

The answer here is in two parts:

`/home/airflow/gcs` is a [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) volume. Using this directory for the DockerVolume just doesn't work (may work by adding a plugin, I lost the link for this :/ )

We want to add a volume inside the airflow-workers, we can do so by updating the kubectl config : 
see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253082/broken-dag-no-module-named-docker/50260721) for the how to update the config. 
We want to add a hostPath:

```
containers:
  ...
  securityContext:
    privileged: true
    runAsUser: 0
    capabilities:
      add: 
      - SYS_ADMIN
  ...
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /etc/airflow/airflow_cfg
    name: airflow-config
  - mountPath: /home/airflow/gcs
    name: gcsdir
  - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    name: docker-host
  - mountPath: /bin/docker
    name: docker-app
  - mountPath: /path/you/want/as/volume
    name: mountname
  ...
  volumes:
  - configMap:
    defaultMode: 420
    name: airflow-configmap
  name: airflow-config
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: gcsdir
  - hostPath:
      path: /path/you/want/as/volume
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: mountname
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      type: ""
    name: docker-host
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/docker
      type: ""
    name: docker-app
```

And now in the DAG definition we can use 
`volume = {"/path/you/want/as/volume": {"bind": "/out/", "mode": "rw"}}`

File will exists inside the POD, and you can use another task to upload them in a gcs bucket or so.

Hope it can help somewhat :)